# Prestashop - featured products by tags

Tags: module, tags, prestashop, title, prestashop-1.6

how to make the Prestashop to showing featured products by tags or title?
I do not want to add a lot of products manually, I would like to make it by tags or title.

Comment: Which version of prestashop?

Comment: Your question is confused, can you explain better what do you want? Because you say 'showing' but after you say 'to add a lot of products manually', this two things are different :)

Comment: @sarcom this is version 1.6.0.9. When you go to "Product edit" and "Associations", you see "Default category" and "Accessories" below it. I want to fill "Accessories" in every product page, but not manually. I want to make it filling auto by products tags or title. Do you understand?

Comment: Now it's more clear ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to pick up a module, search `Related Products by Product’s Tags` on the official addons market of PrestaShop.

To get the products with a specific tag you can use the Search class, for e.g. in your module you have the hook `displayFooterProduct`:

```
public function hookDisplayFooterProduct($params){
    $tags = $this->context->controller->product->tags;
    $id_lang = $this->context->language->id;
    if(is_array($tags) AND count($tags)>1){
        foreach($tags as $tag)
            $products_related = array_merge($products_related, Search::searchTag($id_lang, $tag);
        // I guess here you have to check duplicates and also remove the product that you're viewing
    } else {
        $products_related = Search::searchTag($this->context->language->id, $tags[0])
    }
    // After you have to display results, with a tpl
    $this->smarty->assign(array(
        'products_related' => $products_related
    ));
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/hook/footerproduct.tpl');
}
```

Comment: @ZAM666 I think that 35$ (43 vat incl.) have much more value of 1 or 2 days (in the best case) spent to edit much more of 'some' files or to made up a module :), because that is the right way, make a module :). If you want, I can write a snippet to retrieve the products by tags, but all the module structure it's a your responsibility :)

Comment: @ZAM666 More of that I can't do. Follow the [documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Creating+a+PrestaShop+Module)! to make a new module ;). Cheers ;)